# ExpandoObject in MEF Export

Tags: c#, dynamic, mvvm, mef

**Edit:** `ExpandoObject` works fine with MEF. I just had a syntax error. Silly me.

---

I am currently using `ExpandoObjects` to dynamically create `DelegateCommand`'s for my `ViewModels`.

```
private dynamic _commands = new ExpandoObject();
public dynamic Commands
{
    get
    {
        return _commands;
    }
}

private void initializeCommands()
{
    _commands.TestSql(new DelegateCommand(() => testSqlConnection()));
}
```

This command is used in my `View`.

```
<Button Content="Test Connection" Command={Binding Commands.TestSql}/>
```

I am now updating the code to use MEF and it is working great for most modules. However, when this `ViewModel` is being composed, I get the following exception:

> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is
>   provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for
>   more detailed information.
>
> 1) 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'TestSql'

This error makes sense since `ExpandoObject` doesn't have a property with this name. It should be created dynamically. Has anyone dealt with `ExpandoObjects` in MEF? I could always get rid of the `ExpandoObject` if I have to, but I was wondering if there is an easy fix that would allow this situation to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
private void initializeCommands()
{
    _commands.TestSql = new DelegateCommand( () => testSqlConnection());
}
```

Comment: Wow.. You are right. Since it was compiling fine I didn't even notice that. In all other places in my code I was doing that. Thanks!